# Bower returning error : EHTTP Status code of 401

Tags: npm, bower, bower-install, bower-register

I am getting below error when running `bower install`. The problem seems to be that there is a proxy inside the .bowerrc file. If I am using other location which is not having username and password, it is able to download the library. Please verify if the configuration is correct or anything I am missing.

```
bower                     invalid-meta for:C:\testing\bower.json
bower                     invalid-meta The "name" is recommended to be lowercase, can contain digits, dots, dashes
bower lib#*                 not-cached nexus/repo/path/file.tgz#*
bower lib#*                    resolve nexus/repo/path/file.tgz#*
bower lib#*                   download nexus/repo/path/file.tgz
bower lib#*                      EHTTP Status code of 401
```

bower.json configuration:

```
{

  "name": "testing",
  "version": "1.5.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "lib": "nexus/repo/path/file.tgz"
  }
}
```

.bowerrc configuration:

```
{
  "directory": "",
  "registry": {
    "search": [
      "nexus/repo/path"
    ]
  },
  "resolvers": [
    "bower-nexus3-resolver"
  ],
  "nexus": {
    "username": "test",
    "password": "test"
  }
}
```